# What defines IE 9's default compat and quirk modes?

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml-transitional

Because I"m not specifying a compat mode in my html right now, different users seem to get different modes. When I run the MS Developers Toolbar I see that some users are in IE 9 compat mode, some are in strict mode, etc. I understand **HOW** to force the mode I want but I'd like to understand why IE 9 defaults to different modes for different users. Also, for testing I'd like to set my own IE to the worst case scenario to ensure I've caught all the 1000's of pages I have that this may affect.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered this.  I think it carries with the browser... so if the user has changed it, it will remain for the next sites they go to.
Reason i say this, I had an issue with the browser crashing when trying to change modes.  So I found I could go to Google, change the mode, then go back to the website, staying in that mode no-matter what the HTML told it.